# iOS SparrowFramework

Tags: ios, xcode, sparrow-framework

I don't know what's going on- this is my first iOS development project and I'm trying to get my libraries all set up properly.

I have a framework known as Sparrow and am trying to link that up to my project yet I always get the same error - "Sparrow.h cannot be found/referenced".

I'm following the tutorial exactly [on this site](http://wiki.sparrow-framework.org/tutorials/creating_a_sparrow_project_from_scratch_xcode_4), and I have checked that I have Xcode 4.2. I really have no idea what's going on, I've tried this about 7-8 times now and it always shows that error.

Can anyone give me some insight?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, putting the right path to the header files in User Header Search Paths tends to be the tricky part to get right. I'd suggest you double check that's correct.

Comment: After searching more and more I discovered a lot of people were having issues with the spacing in their Framework path. I moved my Framework to another location and this resolved the issue. Also, was receiving ARC issues afterwords so you need to disable that to get the Framework running properly. Hopefully there's an updated tutorial soon to relieve people of these confusions albeit I am a beginning at this!

Comment: You can exclude just the framework files from ARC, you don't have to disable it for your whole project.